# Vapor 4 fluent. Complex query, filter and create if doesn't exist

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to query a Chat with two users. If it exists I'd like to return it. If not I'd like to create new chat with those two users and return it.

Comment shows where it fails if chat exists.

Also would be helpful if you can show how to create new chat with those two users in this scenario.

```swift
func create(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Chat> {
  
  let currentUser = try req.auth.require(User.self)
  
  guard
    let userID = req.parameters.get("userID"),
    let uuid = UUID(userID)
  else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
  
  return User
    .query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$id == uuid)
    .with(\.$chats)
    .first()
    .unwrap(or: Abort(.internalServerError))
    .flatMap({ chatUser -> EventLoopFuture<Chat> in
      
      let chat = chatUser
        .chats
        .filter({
          $0.users.contains(where: { $0.id == currentUser.id }) // FAILS HERE: Fatal error: Siblings relation not eager loaded, use $ prefix to access: Siblings<Chat, User, ChatUser>(from: [chat_id], to: [user_id]): file
        })
        .first
      
      if let chat = chat {
        
        return req
          .eventLoop
          .makeSucceededFuture(chat)
        
      } else {
        
        // create new chat with those two users and return
        
      }
    })
}
```

Simplified models:

```swift
final class Chat: Model, Content {
  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?
  
  @Siblings(through: ChatUser.self, from: \.$chat, to: \.$user)
  var users: [User]
}

final class User: Model, Content {
  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?
  
  @Siblings(through: ChatUser.self, from: \.$user, to: \.$chat)
  var chats: [Chat]
}

final class ChatUser: Model {
  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  @Parent(key: Keys.chatId)
  var chat: Chat

  @Parent(key: Keys.userId)
  var user: User
}
```

Comment: in late 2021 , It is Better to use async/await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0xTim helped me out on Discord. And I managed to make it work after reading [This doc](https://github.com/vapor/docs/blob/fluent-gm/4.0/docs/fluent/relations.md#nested-eager-load)

Here's working solution:

```swift
func create(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Chat> {
  
  let currentUser = try req.auth.require(User.self)
  
  guard
    let userID = req.parameters.get("userID"),
    let userUUID = UUID(userID)
    else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
  
  return User
    .query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$id == userUUID)
    .with(\.$chats, { chats in
      chats.with(\.$users)
    })
    .first()
    .unwrap(or: Abort(.internalServerError))
    .flatMap({ chatUser -> EventLoopFuture<Chat> in
      
      let chat = chatUser
        .chats
        .filter({
          $0.users.contains(where: { $0.id! == currentUser.id! })
        })
        .first
      
      if let chat = chat {
        
        return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(chat)
        
      } else {
        
        let newChat = Chat()
        return newChat
          .save(on: req.db)
          .flatMap({
            
            newChat
              .$users
              .attach([chatUser, currentUser], on: req.db)
              .flatMap({
                
                return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(newChat)
              })
          })
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that essentially you need to do the further eager load of your `User` model being used in the `ChatUser` model. If it were possible, in your first query, as well as `.with(\.$chats)` you would do something like `.with(\.$chats.$chats)`, but this isn't possible.

In this case, rather than answer your question directly, could I suggest that you think about starting with a query on `ChatUser` instead? If you look for a record in this `Model` that matches and then work accordingly. Something like:

```swift
ChatUser.query(on:req.db).filter(\.$id == currentUser.id).filter(\.$chat == userId).first().map { mayExist in
    if let doesExist = mayExist {
        // work with existing chat
    } else {
        // does not exist so create a new one
        // how, depends on your init for the model
        let newChat = ChatUser( user:currentUser.id!, chat:userId)
        newChat.create(on:req.db).map{
            // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

PS - in a rush to go to work, so this may be full of holes!

Comment: I've added my ChatUser model code. I understand your suggestion. I never thought about making query this way. It certainly helps. I think I'm getting lost when I need to further queries inside `map` or `flatMap`, it's a bit confusing for me right now. I'm waiting for update of RayWenderlich's book on Vapor 4, for sure I'm gonna learn a lot there. Anyway thanks. I'll try your suggestion and if I get something going I'll post here.